# C# Possible to search Google by image and downloading the first one?

Tags: c#, .net, google-image-search

Is there a way to programatically upload an image file to search in Google, and then downloading the first one (the one with best resolution)?

EDIT: The Google Search API would not work for me, as I would have much more than 100 requests per day, and I am not willing to pay, since I am not a company

Comment: I would try th upload with a GoogleAPI, and then get the first one with some HTML thing (eg.: HTMLAgilityPack). The one with the best resolution is harder: I'd get all the resolutions (HTMLAgilityPack, and get int parseable strings like this: 0x0). Then get the best resolution, and the download link for that one. Just the idea, not the code, because i don't know the solution. good luck :)

Comment: But, please remember that on SO you must provide a code snippet, what have you tried...

Comment: @RAPTOR I know of that rule, but first, there isnt such relevant question, second, there is no code that could be tried if thats not possible

Comment: I understand you of course, just tried to explain the reason of the -1s :) I hope Márton's answer will be OK for you

Comment: I’m pretty sure that circumventing the request quota from the API by going a different route (using the normal search interface) is against Google’s terms and conditions.

Comment: thats why I said the Google Search API does not work for my needs

Comment: @poke is right. The API is the only officially supported and legal way. If you want to use the services someone provides and they ask you to pay for it, you should pay for it.

Comment: what do you mean legal? if I can program a software myself that can do that, I will

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer: Possible doesn't make it legal/correct. People have been prosecuted under the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act

Comment: Your assumption that only companies need to pay for services is wrong. Honest people also need to do it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is. The [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) allows you to submit queries (including images) and retrieve results programmatically. There are even [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/libraries) available for multiple languages.

**EDIT**: After OP changed his question, basically saying that he doesn't want to use the Google API, I can only refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469835/how-many-results-does-google-allow-a-request-to-scrape)(a bit outdated) question and quote the Google Terms of Service:

> **1.4 Appropriate Conduct.** You shall not, and shall not allow any third party to: ... (i) directly or indirectly generate queries, or
>   impressions of or clicks on Results, through any automated, deceptive,
>   fraudulent or other invalid means (including, but not limited to,
>   click spam, robots, macro programs, and Internet agents);

So to recap, it **is** possible, but it is only legal via the API I linked above.

Comment: what exactly do I need from there? as usual, I am in a link loophole from the terrible google documentations...

Comment: also, will I have a limit of 100 queries per day with that? Because I will likely need much more

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer I never used this one so you'll have to figure it out. They usually have excellent documentation for their APIs, with introduction and code samples at the second link in my answer. If the documentation states that you have a limit, then probably you have to pay more for a higher quota.

Comment: Violating Terms of Service is not illegal. Illegal means that you go to prison if you do that, a violation of Terms of Service is just an action that potentially exposed you to a civil action against you from Google