# Too Many Request(Google Search API)

Tags: web-scraping, google-search-api

I am trying to perform scrapping using google search API ( **[www.google.com/search?q=keyword](http://www.google.com/search?q=keyword)** ). I am calling this API and giving a keyword in each loop iteration. I also pause the process in each iteration in order to give a delay between each API call.

This process works fine when I check it in India, but when I try to run it from another location ex. Israel, it gives **Too Many Request **error.

**Do Google Search Limits differ country wise?**

Would really appreciate your response on this issue.

Comment: Google Anaytics says [50,000 requests per project per day, which can be increased. 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP address](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas)

Comment: I am not using the official search API, instead I am using (www.google.com/search?q=keyword) for scrapping.
Any solution for that? @DanielSabrel

Comment: Simple solution is to limit your searches and add delay. Even after that it **will** detect you as automated bot after some time. Google don't want it to be scraped and Google knows you. So, it is hard to beat that. [Here is same question asked](https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/issues/18) and [here as well for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469835/how-many-results-does-google-allow-a-request-to-scrape/22702983#22702983)